# Can't select date with datepickerdialog

Tags: kotlin

I have some trouble using the DataPickerDialog in kotlin... 
This is how I would like it to work:
First, when the user selects a date, it must update a textview and the dialog must close
But for now, when the user selects a date, nothing happens (apart from the update in the dialog itself). 
Here is my code :

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class AppointmentListFragment : Fragment() {

    private var _binding: FragmentAppointmentListBinding? = null
    private val binding: FragmentAppointmentListBinding
        get() = _binding!!

    private val viewModel: AppointmentMainViewModel by viewModels()
    private val today = Calendar.getInstance()
    private val day = today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
    private val month = today.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1
    private val year = today.get(Calendar.YEAR)

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentAppointmentListBinding.inflate(inflater)
        setDateText(
            getString(
                R.string.date_placeholder,
                String.format("%02d", day),
                String.format("%02d", month),
                year
            )
        )

        binding.appointmentDateButton.setOnClickListener {
            val dpd = DatePickerDialog(
                it.context,
                { datePicker, y, m, d ->
                    datePicker.minDate = System.currentTimeMillis()
                    setDateText(
                        getString(
                            R.string.date_placeholder,
                            String.format("%02d", d),
                            String.format("%02d", m),
                            y
                        )
                    )
                },
                year,
                month,
                day
            )
            dpd.show()
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun setDateText(date: String) {
        binding.appointmentDateButton.text = date
    }
```

What am I missing ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What do you get in `setDateText`? I copied almost all code and launched. Then got `y`, `m`, `d` inside `onDateSet` callback. So, a string

```
getString(
    R.string.date_placeholder,
    String.format("%02d", d),
    String.format("%02d", m),
    y
)
```

should be right (but I don't know what you have put in `date_placeholder`).

So, this string is passed to `setDateText` and is written in `appointmentDateButton` (19 05 2022). I don't know, what happened.

By the way, initial month is incremented by 1. It's a mistake (you open the picker on 19th' June).

Comment: That's the point `setDateText` is never called inside the `onDateSetListener`...
`date_placeholder` is only a way to format the date, it's "just return" 20/05/2022.
Regarding the incrementation of the month, I need it to show the good month on the `appointmentDateButton` without it, I get "20/04/2022", but I agree with you that I am not doing the incrementation at the right place

Comment: @YohDono, thanks! Please, remove (comment) `DatePickerDialog` at all and retain only `binding.appointmentDateButton.setOnClickListener { setDateText(getString(...)) }`. Will it write a new text?

Comment: So I did what you said and if I set the date directly when I click on `appointmentDateButton`, it work properly and set the new date. When the `DatepickerDialog` is open, it's like that the `onDateSet` is not being call

Comment: Sooo I gave up... I ended up making my own `DatePickerDialog` which, since I'm not schizophrenic, works just the way I want. But the mystery remains... and thank you @CoolMind for your help

Comment: @YohDono, wow, what a large job you made! I wanted to ask you to copy this code to a new project and run. It will execute correctly. Then you can find in the first project, what happens. Maybe change a library (or import correct). Or check ViewModel.

Comment: You can also debug the app and find why `onDateSet` is not being call. Maybe it is called but `setDateText` doesn't change text.

Comment: It's was not so much work... Way faster than fix this bug ! I made a new projet and run it and it's work properly... I really don't know what is the issue so for now I will keep using my custom date picker and maybe one day I will try again to fix the bug